# rails includes multiple 2 level associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table invoices with a column PRODUCT. Products table then belongs to other tables such as categories, suppliers etc..

In my view I need to display:

```
invoice.product.CATEGORY
inventory.product.SUPPLIER
```

I am trying to setup my controller to avoid n+1 queries.

So I did:

```
@invoices = Invoice.all.includes(product => category, product => supplier)
```

I have bullet gem installed, and it shows that there/s a n+1 query detected `Product => [category]` and `Add to your finder::includes => [:category]`

It seems considering only the latest of the includes and ignore the others. I suppose my syntax is wrong.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You didn't symbolize your models.

```
@invoices = Invoice.all.includes(:product => :category, :product => :supplier)
```

This can be shortened by using an array:

```
@invoices = Invoice.all.includes(:product => [:category, :supplier])
```

It's idiomatic to put your `.where` or `.limit` (or `.all`) at the end:

```
@invoices = Invoice.includes(:product => [:category, :supplier]).all
```

Why not make a scope?

**controller**

```
def index
  @invoices = Invoice.with_details.all
end
```

**model**

```
class Invoice
  # ...
  def self.with_details
    includes(:product => [:category, :supplier])
  end
end
```

Even better:

**controller**

```
def index
  @invoices = Invoice.with_details(params[:qty])
end
```

**model**

```
class Invoice
  # ...
  def self.with_details(num)
    includes(:product => [:category, :supplier]).limit(num)
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi thanks that worked! Only thing in the last solution I don't really understand what `scan(/\d/)` is and what is that doing? And if not too bother why is that better than the simple scope on second solution?

Comment: It's not really necessary, I should take it out. It's just making sure that the limit is an actual number. The `.scan` method returns an array of the regex matches (`\d` is a digit) `['1','2','3']` and joins them back together `['123']`.

Comment: Alright. I think I'll use second solution which is 100% clear to me and that's better in case I run into issues to debug in the future. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry last thing. You asked if it should be :categories. database table is categories. But that refers to the model which has singular name, hence :category. Isn't that correct?

Comment: Yeah, I'll take that out. It applies to joins.

Comment: Actually I think singular has to be used with joins too. At least that's what I usually do and it works.

Comment: Thanks @Eric for the very useful & detailed answer :)

Comment: thoroughly demonstrated the syntax. Thanks very much!